# QMessageBox doesn't execute properly in sys.excepthook

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm currently working on a GUI with multiple threads using PyQt5 with Python and I'd like to implement a sys.excepthook that displays a QMessageBox showing a generic error message.

Basically if an uncaught error occurs anywhere, this QMessageBox should be displayed and the program should exit after closing this QMessagebox.

Here is my current approach and the weird behaviour I'm receiving:

1. I overwrite `sys.excepthook` with my own function: `sys.excepthook = default_except_hook`. This is the first line that gets executed in the code.
2. This is what default_except_hook looks like:

```
def default_except_hook(cls, exception, traceback):
    
    sys.__excepthook__(cls, exception, traceback)

    messagebox = QMessageBox()
    messagebox.setWindowTitle("An unexcepted error occured!")
    messagebox.setText("...")
    messagebox.setIcon(getattr(QMessageBox, "Critical"))
    messagebox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
    messagebox.exec_()
```

For testing I put uncaught dummy-errors in the code at different places.

- In the main GUI class everything works as excepted.
- When an uncaught error happens in a worker class in a QThread, either one of two weird things happen:

  1. The QMessageBox gets displayed correctly, but the program doesn't wait for the user to close the QMessageBox. Instead, the QMessageBox and the whole program exits after a few seconds.
  2. Only the window title of the QMessagebox gets displayed. The whole program and python stops responding.[image: faulty error message]

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: That's not so weird: widgets are *not* thread-safe, and you're clearly trying to *create* and *show* a widget from an external thread.

Comment: Showing a message-box inside an except-hook can be very dangerous (even if it's made thread-safe). Some exceptions can be raised repeatedly, which will result in an endless series of message-boxes stacked on top of each other. It's also possible that a future bug could raise an exception from the message-box code itself, which would result in an infinite regression. Needless to say, the design of the except-hook must be thought through very carefully in order to avoid making a bad situation even worse.